# Why appears the "GBP10.00" instead of "10.00"?

Tags: laravel

I have a model where I have this function:

```
public function showPrice(){
return money_format('%i€', $this->price);
}
```

Then in the view is used like:

```
<span>X {{$prod->pshowPrice()}}</span>
```

But instead of appear 10.00€ appear GBP10.00€.

Do you know why?

Comment: this is how `money_format` works, probably you want `number_format` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` formats the number based on the format used to describe the currency of the current locale

What you're seeing is expected if you're using a locale of `en-gb`

Something like `money_format('%i!', $this->price)` will show it with no currency info  (where `!` is a flag which suppresses the currency symbol)